# Documentation for NSString sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode: method (in the iPhone SDK)?

Tags: ios, nsstring, iphone-sdk-documentation

I can't find the documentation for the NSString sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode: method (see [Kevin Ballard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/582/kevin-ballard)'s answer to "[Sizing a UILabel (in the iPhone SDK) to fit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406212/sizing-a-uilabel-in-the-iphone-sdk-to-fit)") in the NSString Class Reference in the iPhone SDK Developer Documentation.  Where should I look?

**Update**: I hadn't subscribed to an iPhone OS Library doc set, so my search didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In XCode, look for `sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:`. Make sure you have the iPhone docset selected/available.

It's also [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:), if you're logged into your developer account.

Answer (score 5):

This has been answered and accepted, but just one more comment:

The sizeWithFont:* methods are not strictly part of NSString. They are categories of NSString added by UIKit.

That's probably why your search didn't work before you subscribed to the iPhone OS doc set.