# How do I get -[NSString sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:] to work?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I updated my question "[Sizing a UILabel (in the iPhone SDK) to fit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406212/sizing-a-uilabel-in-the-iphone-sdk-to-fit)" with a description of my problem with a suggested solution, but didn't get an answer.  Perhaps I'll have better results by asking a new question...

I set a breakpoint after the following code:

```
NSString *theText = @"When in the Course of human events, it becomes necessary for one people to dissolve the political bands which have connected them with another, and to assume among the powers of the earth, the separate and equal station to which the Laws of Nature and of Nature's God entitle them, a decent respect to the opinions of mankind requires that they should declare the causes which impel them to the separation.";
CGSize theSize = [theText sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f] forWidth:260.0 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

`theSize.height` is 21 and `theSize.width` is 231. What am I doing wrong? That height can't be in pixels nor in number of lines.

Note that `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f]` is meant to specify the default font.

**Update**: I changed the code to:

```
CGSize constraintSize;
constraintSize.width = 260.0f;
constraintSize.height = MAXFLOAT;
NSString *theText = @"When in the Course of human events, it becomes necessary for one people to dissolve the political bands which have connected them with another, and to assume among the powers of the earth, the separate and equal station to which the Laws of Nature and of Nature's God entitle them, a decent respect to the opinions of mankind requires that they should declare the causes which impel them to the separation.";
CGSize theSize = [theText sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f] constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

`theSize.height` is 273.  That seems more like it.

Comment: I had the exact same result: 21.  Anyone know where that number comes from, or is it just based on that font size.  Silly method.

Comment: If you're using a UITextView, have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330939/sizewithfont-doesnt-give-correct-height-for-uitextview-if-there-is-a-long-strin/15408198#15408198

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That height is in pixels. I expect it's truncating, i.e. giving you the metrics you'd see if you set this text on a UILabel with 1 line.

Try using `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:` and just give it `MAXFLOAT` for the height component of the size.

Comment: If the text is long enough, creating a view with maximum height MAXFLOAT will cause the application to crash.

Answer (score 7):

As anyone who has puzzled this out learns, the method is inappropriately named and rather inconsistent with what you'd expect (that's a violation of good API design, but as any seasoned dev knows: Apple's API is not well designed, sorry guys).  Worth reading: [Josh Bloch's presentation](http://lcsd05.cs.tamu.edu/slides/keynote.pdf) on good API design.

I'd posit that they should rename it (if it must be kept) and make this one useful, such that you don't end up using the common practice of passing in a `CGSize` with a size you know is much too large.

```
[someString sizeWithFont:yourFont 
       constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(maxWidthYouSpecify, self.frame.size.height)  
           lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Alternately this would work just as well:

```
[someString sizeWithFont:yourFont 
       constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(maxWidthYouSpecify, CGFLOAT_MAX)
           lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

This is, arguably, how the function should work.  (FWIW, `CGFLOAT_MAX` is defined in [CGGeometry](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html))

An aside, but rather important: all Core Graphics deal in points not pixels.

> One point does not necessarily correspond to one pixel on the screen.

That's an important distinction and one you need to understand when dealing with different resolutions (iPhone 3GS vs 4 vs iPad, etc).  See Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html) and Command+F for "Points vs Pixels".