# How can I make text in a UILabel non-centered?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I have a UILabel:

```
    descriptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 30, 130, 150)];
    [descriptionLabel setFont:[Utils getSystemFontWithSize:14]];
    [descriptionLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [descriptionLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    descriptionLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    [self addSubview:descriptionLabel];
```

If the text is only 1 line long it will appear in the middle of the label.

**Is there anyway I can have the text display from the top left corner of the label instead of the middle center?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set

`[descriptionLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];`

or if you prefer dot syntax

`descriptionLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;`

Comment: Unfortunately, the text still appears in the middle after making these changes.

Comment: Do you mean vertically in the middle? It is left-aligned though yeah?

You could set the height of your label after calculating with NSString's sizeWithFont method — more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455553/what-is-nsstring-sizewithfontforwidthlinebreakmode-good-for

Answer (score 0):

for left/right alignment set the `textAlignment` property of UILabel to either `UITextAlignmentLeft` or `UITextAlignmentRight`.

for more fine tuning you can override `drawTextInRect:`