# How to calculate size of a string using custom font

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4

I have a Label that displays some text like "I am good". How can I calculate the size of text in Label that has custom font. I am calculating size like

```
CGSize s = [mSubLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ArnhemPro-Blond.otf" size:10.0] constrainedToSize:Max_Size lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];

NSLog(@"expected size %@",NSStringFromCGSize(s));
```

But the size is **(0,0)**

How can i calculate the size? using `GSize subLabelSize=[mSubLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:1] constrainedToSize:Max_Size lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];`

gives me size but that is not correct.help please...

Comment: The link has your answer.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527494/how-to-calculate-uilabel-width-based-on-text-length

Comment: @mihirios: I am using custom fonts not the font of Label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your font is most likely `nil`, the `name` parameter for `fontNamed:` should be the *name* of the font which is usually different from its filename (and has no extension). You can use the Font Book app to find out the actual name of a font.

Comment: I have removed the extension but still size is (0,0)

Comment: Btw, make sure you have a proper license for the font. The usual licenses that you can buy online normally don't allow to embed them in apps, you'd need to have a special license for that and those tend to be expensive...

Comment: ...and make sure that you've included the font in your Info.plist.

Comment: I have purchased fonts and also I have added them info.plist. Now I am able to get size but when I try to get size for bold text it shows (0,0). Any how I will your answer is correct if I am to get size for bold text too.

Comment: I know I can make text bold by adding  -Bold after font name

Comment: Have you also included the bold font file and added it to your Info.plist? The bold font is in a different file than the normal font...

Comment: Thanks omz. I will buy bold fonts too