# how can I set UILabel width dynamically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` and its text is generated dynamically, so depending upon text, `UILabel` width increases from `iOS6 to iOS8`. Is there any solution for this? it is only working on iOS7 and in iOS6.0 `boundingRectWithSize` method is crashing, its say `boundingRectWithSize` method only for iOS7.0 and above.

```
float widthIs =[[tagsArray objectAtIndex:i] boundingRectWithSize:_tagsValue.frame.size options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:_tagsValue.font } context:nil].size.width;
_tagsValue.frame=CGRectMake(prevTag, 2, widthIs+20, 30);
prevTag+=widthIs+30;
```

Comment: Tell us how it's *NOT working* on iOS 6 and 8? Any screenshots?

Comment: `boundingRectWithSize` method is crashing in iOS 6 and its only working on above ios7

Comment: This method will crash application when you run on device with IOS6. As boundingRectWithSize method introduced in IOS7.

Comment: Then edit your question and add the crash detail including the error/warning message. We can't guess.

Comment: @RameshKumar try with UITextview. Make editing disable.

Comment: @kathiravanG can i set textview background color below iOS7

Comment: @RameshKumar u can set textview backgoundcolor in iOS 6.

Comment: Did you try using `sizeToFit`?

Comment: @hotLicks `sizeToFit` for both iOS6 and iOS7

Comment: Look this question, maybe help you: [Here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527494/how-to-calculate-uilabel-width-based-on-text-length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put a check for iOS6 and iOS7,

> ```
> if([[[tagsArray objectAtIndex:i] respondsToSelector:@selector(boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:)]){
>     float widthIs =[[tagsArray objectAtIndex:i] boundingRectWithSize:_tagsValue.frame.size options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:_tagsValue.font } context:nil].size.width;
>     _tagsValue.frame=CGRectMake(prevTag, 2, widthIs+20, 30);
>     prevTag+=widthIs+30;
> }
> else{
>     float widthIs = [[[tagsArray objectAtIndex:i] sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:(CGSize){CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX}];
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Use this, this will work on IOS6 & IOS7. But I am not sure about IOS8 as i haven't test it on IOS8.

```
float width = [LABEL_TEXT_STRING sizeWithFont:LABEL_FONT constrainedToSize:DEFAULT_SIZE_OF_LABEL lineBreakMode:LABEL.lineBreakMode].width;
```

Comment: depreciated method use

Answer (score -1):

Use this method to get the Width
 Pass your label as param

```
 - (CGFloat)getWidth:(UILabel *)label{

      CGSize sizeOfText = [label.text boundingRectWithSize: CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, self.bounds.size.height)
                                                  options: (NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                               attributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:label.font
                                                forKey:NSFontAttributeName]
                                                  context: nil].size;

    return sizeOfText.width; 

    }
```

Comment: Its only available for iOS7.