# NSString where does the linebreak go

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to split a `NSString` into several lines with different width, I find this method `[NSString sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:]` in the doc,but it doesn't provide the position
where the linebreak take place. Is there any method in IOS that works like the following in Symbian:

```
class CFont :
TextCount()
IMPORT_C TInt TextCount(const TDesC &aText, TInt aWidthInPixels) const;
```

> Description Gets how much of the
>   specified descriptor can be displayed
>   in this font without exceeding the
>   specified width.
>
> Note:
>
> This function does not display any of
>   the descriptor itself - it is used
>   before display, to test whether the
>   whole descriptor can be displayed.
>
> Parameters:
>
> const TDesC &aText The
>   descriptor.    TInt aWidthInPixels The
>   available width for character display.
>
> Return value:
>
> TInt  The number of characters which will be able to be displayed
>   without exceeding the specified width.
>   The count starts from the beginning of
>   the descriptor.

```
TextCount()
IMPORT_C TInt TextCount(const TDesC &aText, TInt aWidthInPixels) const;
```

> Description:
>   Gets how much of the specified descriptor can be displayed in this
>   font without exceeding the specified
>   width.
>
> Note:
>
> This function does not display any of the descriptor itself - it is used
>   before display, to test whether the
>   whole descriptor can be displayed.
>
> Parameters:
>
> const TDesC &aText The descriptor.
>
> TInt aWidthInPixels The available width for character display.
>
> Return value:
>
> TInt  The number of characters which will be able to be displayed
>   without exceeding the specified width.
>   The count starts from the beginning of
>   the descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

I think that

```
sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:
```

maybe what you need. see [What is -[NSString sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:] good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455553/what-is-nsstring-sizewithfontforwidthlinebreakmode-good-for)

Comment: beacuse I want to get the string each line,but these method only provide the string’s bounding box.