# Shrink custom textLabel and detailTextLabel in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, textlabel, detailtextlabel

I'm using a slightly customized version of [Loren Brichter's Fast Scrolling script](http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/) and I'm having a problem where the labels in the cells don't stop if they reach the end of the cell. When programming table views the standard way, if the `textLabels` or `detailTextLabels` are too long, they automatically cut off and apply three dots at the end of the string to stay within the cell.

I want to do exactly the same thing, but I have no idea how to achieve it. Here is the code I use when adding text to the table view cell:

```
CGPoint t;
CGPoint d;

t.x = feedImage.size.width + 10 + 12;
t.y = 20;
[textLabel drawAtPoint:t withFont:textLabelFont];

d.x = feedImage.size.width + 10 + 12;
d.y = 39;
[detailTextLabel drawAtPoint:d withFont:detailTextLabelFont];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followed [this tutorial](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/truncate-an-nsstring-and-append-an-ellipsis-respecting-the-font-size.html). Works seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically find out (using approx. character widths) which would be the last two/three characters visible. Then remove the remaining characters and put the three dots yourself! For upper case characters try a width of 16 and for lower-case, a width of 12 points for a font-size of 15. find out the right numbers by trial and error.

Ok. Here's a function that adjusts the label height(for a given width) according to the characters. The variable "width" is the width of the label and "tempWidth" is the width of current row being calculated. You can modify this function to return the truncated string with the three dots at the end...

```
#define smallLetterWidth 12
#define capitalLetterWidth 16
-(int) numRowsForString:(NSString *) inputStr width:(int) width{
int j=0;
numRows=1;
int tempWidth = 0;
while(j<[inputStr length]){
    if([[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[inputStr characterAtIndex:j]])
        tempWidth += capitalLetterWidth;
    else
        tempWidth += smallLetterWidth;
     if(tempWidth>width){
        tempWidth = 0;
        numRows++;
        j--;
    }
    else if(tempWidth==width)
    {
        tempWidth = 0;
        numRows++;
    }
    j++;
}
return  numRows;
}
```

Even better: [What is -[NSString sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:] good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455553/what-is-nsstring-sizewithfontforwidthlinebreakmode-good-for)

Comment: This doesn't exactly seem like a reliable way to do this. Isn't there a function that can cut off a string by only feeding it a pixel width? That would be awesome.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no function for this. I know it's not an exact way but it's the only way...

Comment: Can you provide some examples on how to do this, then?

Comment: hmmm...the iOS developer tricks method does the same thing but in a more exact way. I did'nt know how to find the exact width so I resorted to trial and error!