# How would I change the vertical size of a UICollectionView Cell depending upon the amount of text I put in a UITextbox?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, uicollectionview

I would like to have variable height UICollectionView cells depending upon the amount of text that I'm putting in a UItextbox that I've defined through storyboard. I've tried a few options from Googling but nothing has worked.

Any help would be more than appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways of knowing the size of a `UILabel` or `UITextView`, based on their **content**. I would advise calculating that, before asking for it's size while the `UICollectionViewDelegate's` methods are requesting the height of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the size of the NSString with font. [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455553/what-is-nsstring-sizewithfontforwidthlinebreakmode-good-for)

That will get you a CGSize that you can use to adjust the size of your view.