# Why is sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: returning an incorrect size?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have two possible widths for a string i want to display in a label in a table cell, and i need to compute the height so that the table cell's height is recorded correctly.  however, no matter what I do for the constraining size i get the same height, which is incorrect in the case i want.  The code i'm using:

```
CGFloat width = 300.0f;
NSString * value = @"LongText LongText LongText LongText LongText LongText";
CGSize contentSize = [value sizeWithFont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 14.0f]
                       constrainedToSize: CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                           lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

When i inspect the contentSize variable, the width is 252 and the height is 36 which is expected.  But if instead of 300.0f i plug in 222.0f into the width variable, the width is 189 but the height is still 36, and only the first 4 LongText words are displayed on 2 lines (the third line seems to be cut off somehow in the calculation).  Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: If you're using a UITextView, have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330939/sizewithfont-doesnt-give-correct-height-for-uitextview-if-there-is-a-long-strin/15408198#15408198

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks right.  Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455553/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419222/) to see if there is anything amiss in your code.

Comment: Thanks, but those don't really explain why the method isn't behaving correctly for thinner widths.

Comment: No, your code should be working.  I thought maybe you'd see a difference between their code and yours... I didn't.

Comment: right; i'm just wondering if anyone else is aware that the apple code that actually calculates the size is not correct and if there is an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out it is returning the correct size; the code i was working on was using incorrect widths instead of the widths from this method which is why the text was cut off and i was confused.