# Setting UITextView frame to content size no longer works in Xcode 5

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

The code snippet below worked to resize a UITextView frame to it's content height, before installing Xcode 5 but it doesn't work since the upgrade:

```
CGRect frame = _textView.frame;
frame.size.height = _textView.contentSize.height;
_textView.frame = frame;
```

I've searched and haven't found the fix.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's new stuff for this on iOS 7.

To get the "fitted" size used by the text view after it's updated its text, call `usedRectForTextContainer:` on the textView's `layoutManager` property, passing the textView's `textContainer` property as an argument.

Word of warning about scrolling: Be advised, though, that changing the frame size of a text view *after* it has updated it's text can have unexpected visual bugs if scrolling is disabled on your text view. If this happens, set scrolling enabled before editing the text of the text view, then disabling it after it's updated (if you need scrolling to remain disabled).

Comment: Brilliant! It works, Thanks! I would give this answer a point but I don't have enough rep :(

Comment: I am struggling with this, and can't get it to work, can you provide a sample code?

Thanks.

Comment: A code example would be useful.  I interpreted your answer as `[[textView layoutManager] usedRectForTextContainer:[textView textContainer]];` which doesn't resize the textView's height to fit the contents

Comment: `usedRectForTextContainer:` is not intended to resize anything. It's a way to obtain the exact rect that contains the text that the textView has drawn. What you do with that CGRect is up to each app.

Comment: Does not work for me -- `usedRectForTextContainer` sometimes returns an enormous large number for height, and sometimes returns an incorrect number based on the previous content of the textView (ie, what you just replaced with `textView.text = newString`).

Comment: I can't believe this.. I was really struggling with why the textView wasn't returning the correct size, so as you suggested, I turned on scrolling... it worked...

Comment: @croald it may be an issue of **when** you make this call. I've had instances where I had to defer the call to `usedRectForTextContainer:` until the view layout is complete, for example, in a `-[ViewController viewDidLayoutSubviews]` call. Calling that same method earlier in the process gave me the wrong result.

Answer (score 14):

To work in iOS 7 (Xcode 5), just:

1. Give the entire space to receive the text, by setting:

   `[myTextView setScrollEnabled:YES];`
2. Pass the real text:

   `myTextView.text = theTextVariable;` or `myTextView.text = @"The text...";`
3. Autoresize textView:

   `[myTextView sizeToFit];`
4. Disable scroll:

   `[myTextView setScrollEnabled:NO];`

**P.S: myTextView can be use also as self.myTextView or _myTextView**

And have fun!

Comment: Does not work for me -- I need to use `[textView layoutIfNeeded]` instead (see answer below).  I'm really puzzled why some people think this works and others (not just me) clearly don't.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the correct way to force a textView to update its contentSize is by calling

```
[textView layoutIfNeeded]
```

However, in iOS 7.0 and 7.1 this seems still not to work reliably unless you first set

```
textView.layoutManager.allowsNonContiguousLayout = false;
```

It's not clear to me whether this is a bug or not since I can't really find a good explanation of what "non-contiguous layout" even means.

(My personal use case is updating `textView.text = newValue` programmatically, then trying to resize the textView appropriately.)

Comment: been searching all day - this is the only solution that worked for me. thank you.

Comment: allowsNonContiguousLayout is still the key in solving the problem in iOS 9! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
[textView sizeToFit];
```

Is what you need.

All you need to do is make sure that:

```
[textView setScrollEnabled:YES];
```

BEFORE you set the UITextView text content.

You can then:

```
[textView sizeToFit];
[textView setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

After you've set the text. Same as writing your own bling function or employing complicated bounding rect methods. Why use something so complicated when the solution is as simple as three lines?

That said, wrap those functions like so:

```
- (void) setText:(NSString *)theTextToAdd andResizeTheDamnTextView:(UITextView *)textView {
    [textView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [textView setText:theTextToAdd];
    [textView sizeToFit];
    [textView setScrollEnabled:NO];
}
```

And define it in a per-file or global basis to avoid having to manually write or copy/paste the four lines and call it every time. Just call it as:

```
[yourTextViewIvar setText:@"DUMMY STRING" andResizeTheDamnTextView:yourTextViewIvar];
```

If that doesn't work:

```
[yourTextViewIvar setText:[self setText:@"DUMMY STRING" andResizeTheDamnTextView:yourTextViewIvar]];
```

And you'll be golden.

I think..

That's Pseudocode. Just FYI.

Comment: I have a `UITextView *commentTextView` and in `-viewWillAppear` I update the content using `commentTextView.text = commentStringForItem`.  (I sometimes also update it in response to a UI action.)  Then I want to resize the field so that it shows as much of the comment as possible, so I attempt to check `commentTextView.contentSize`.  This value is incorrect (not updated from its previous value) unless I first call `[commentTextView layoutIfNeeded]` -- `sizeToFit` does not work.

Comment: Following `sizeToFit` with `commentTextView.scrollEnabled = false; commentTextView.scrollEnabled = true;` does not seem to help. (I want scrollEnabled on my field in the general case.)  Also, `sizeToFit` messes with the width of my field, when I only want to adjust its height.

Comment: Just make sure `.scrollEnabled` is `TRUE` before you call `sizeToFit` and it should definitely update accordingly. Feel free to leave `scrollEnabled` set to `TRUE`. the `FALSE` was only there for people who don't want it interacted with.

Answer (score -1):

A easier solution is use that:

```
[textViewExample sizeToFit];
```

This work for me.