# Getting rid of whitespace inside a TextView in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode6, autolayout

I have an issue on iOS devices larger than 4 inches.

[image]

As you can see, there is a large gap of whitespace at the bottom of my Text View. I am wondering how to clean it up to remove this whitespace using Interface Builder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change your bottom constraint to >= current value instead of equal and the UITextView will start resizing provided scrolling enabled is unchecked.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to uncheck

```
Scrolling Enabled
```

[image]

[image]

Got the answers [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859637/setting-uitextview-frame-to-content-size-no-longer-works-in-xcode-5)

Comment: I already had the Scrolling Enabled box unchecked, and I was still getting this issue for some reason with the white space. How do I restrict the text field in size?

Answer (score 1):

**Auto - Resizing**
If you are using the auto-resizing for the text view then remove set the following setting for the auto-resizing tab.

This might be your settings, for the text view

[image]

Change it to the following setting,

[image]

Do not stretch the content of the text view,
And if you are worried about the content not displaying in the set height then that is not an issue, there is a already a scroll in the text view controller, make sure that is enabled.

**Auto - Layout**
If You are using Auto Layout in your app then set the constraints as shown in the below image on your text view,

[image]

Add these four constraints,
Left, right, top and the height of the text view.