# Replacement for deprecated -sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, nsstring, sizewithfont

In iOS 7, the method:

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font
     constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size
         lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
```

and the method:

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font
```

are deprecated. How can I replace

```
CGSize size = [string sizeWithFont:font
                 constrainedToSize:constrainSize
                     lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

and:

```
CGSize size = [string sizeWithFont:font];
```

Comment: the substitute method is `-sizeWithAttributes:`.

Comment: ok holex thanks but, how can I use a font from label like a NSDIctionary? if my code is like: sizeWithFont:customlabel.font ;the void ask "sizeWithAttributes:<#(NSDictionary *)#>"

Comment: here is the official documentation of how you can define attributes: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011688

Answer (score 222, accepted):

You could try this:

```
CGRect textRect = [text boundingRectWithSize:size
                                 options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                              attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:FONT}
                                 context:nil];

CGSize size = textRect.size;
```

Just change "FONT" for an "[UIFont font....]"

Comment: And where do you mention NSLineBreakByWordWrapping? Wherre did it go?

Comment: `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` would go within a `NSParagraphStyle`. So for example: `NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;`
In the attributes you would then need to add `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle.copy`...

Comment: @ffried in my case adding the paragraphStyle with line break other than NSLineBreakByWordWrapping caused size to be calculated for just one line… Any thoughts?

Comment: @manicaesar Except for `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` and `NSLineBreakByCharWrapping` all line break modes are made for only one line (by truncating the string). I've just tested it and all line break modes work as expected.

Comment: Don't forget that `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` returns fractional values. You need to do `ceil(textRect.size.height)` and `ceil(textRect.size.width)` respectively to get the real height/width.

Comment: Hmm, you are right, having (for example) NSLineBreakModeByTruncatingMiddle makes no sense for multiple lines. If someone want to have last line with tail truncated, he can use NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine. Thanks!

Comment: Does this return exact size same as sizeWithFont ? I am facing this issue and using the above method still has a height difference of 3 to 4 pixels which causes lot of difference in UI for iOS 6.0 and iOS 7.0 when compared side by side

Comment: boundingRectWithSize is not returning correct width and height.

Comment: What the heck is BOLIVIASize?

Comment: boundingRectWithSize is still returning wrong output as i test it. The scenario is when you are testing for long and multiple paragraphs.

Comment: @Nirav I faced the same problem for long paragraph, but after investigating the problem I found that I provide not accurate attributes like the font size. It was 12 and it should be 14 as in the interface builder in my case

Comment: `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` is represented by  `NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin`.

Answer (score 36):

As we cant use sizeWithAttributes for all iOS greater than 4.3 we have to write conditional code for 7.0 and previous iOS.

**1) Solution 1:**

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
   CGSize size = CGSizeMake(230,9999);
   CGRect textRect = [specialityObj.name  
       boundingRectWithSize:size
                    options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                 attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:[AppHandlers zHandler].fontName size:14]}
                    context:nil];
   total_height = total_height + textRect.size.height;   
}
else {
   CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(230,9999); 
   expectedLabelSize = [specialityObj.name sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:[AppHandlers zHandler].fontName size:14] constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap]; //iOS 6 and previous. 
   total_height = total_height + expectedLabelSize.height;
}
```

**2) Solution 2**

```
UILabel *gettingSizeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
gettingSizeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:[AppHandlers zHandler].fontName size:16]; // Your Font-style whatever you want to use.
gettingSizeLabel.text = @"YOUR TEXT HERE";
gettingSizeLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(310, 9999); // this width will be as per your requirement

CGSize expectedSize = [gettingSizeLabel sizeThatFits:maximumLabelSize];
```

**The first solution is sometime fail to return proper value of height. so use another solution. which will work perfectly.**

The second option is quite well and working smoothly in all iOS without conditional code.

Comment: why 230, 999? Where do you get the number>

Comment: The 230 can be any number. It represents the width you want for your label. The 9999 I'd rather replace with INFINITY or MAXFLOAT.

Comment: Second solution is working like a charm. Thanks Nirav.

Comment: "[AppHandlers zHandler]" gives an error.. "Undeclared Identifiers". How to solve that?

Answer (score 9):

Here is simple solution :

Requirements :

```
CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(widthHere, MAXFLOAT);
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:sizeHere];
```

Now As `constrainedToSizeusage:lineBreakMode:` usage is deprecated in **iOS 7.0**:

```
CGSize expectedSize = [stringHere sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:maximumSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

Now usage in **greater** version of **iOS 7.0** will be:

```
// Let's make an NSAttributedString first
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:stringHere];
//Add LineBreakMode
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
[paragraphStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[attributedString setAttributes:@{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle} range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];
// Add Font
[attributedString setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font} range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];

//Now let's make the Bounding Rect
CGSize expectedSize = [attributedString boundingRectWithSize:maximumSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil].size;
```

Answer (score 7):

Below are two simple methods that will replace these two deprecated methods.

And here are the relevant references:

If you are using NSLineBreakByWordWrapping, you don't need to specify the NSParagraphStyle, as that is the default:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSParagraphStyle_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSParagraphStyle/defaultParagraphStyle

You must get the ceil of the size, to match the deprecated methods' results.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:

```
+ (CGSize)text:(NSString*)text sizeWithFont:(UIFont*)font {    
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}];
    return CGSizeMake(ceilf(size.width), ceilf(size.height));
}

+ (CGSize)text:(NSString*)text sizeWithFont:(UIFont*)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size{
    CGRect textRect = [text boundingRectWithSize:size
                                     options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                  attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}
                                     context:nil];
    return CGSizeMake(ceilf(textRect.size.width), ceilf(textRect.size.height));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In most cases I used the method **sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:** to estimate the minimum size for a **UILabel** to accomodate its text (especially when the label has to be placed inside a UITableViewCell)...

...If this is *exactly* your situation you can simpy use the method:

```
CGSize size = [myLabel textRectForBounds:myLabel.frame limitedToNumberOfLines:mylabel.numberOfLines].size;
```

Hope this might help.

Comment: Apple's documentation says that you should not call this method directly.

Comment: Not mentioned in iOS 7 SDK documentation at least.

Answer (score 3):

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
CGRect new = [string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(200, 300) options:NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font} context:nil];
CGSize stringSize= new.size;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Do not post a same answer again. If you need to add something to an answer, make a comment or do an edit to the answer.

Comment: ok..I will take that into consideration next time.Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

[Accepted answer works nicely in a category. I'm overwriting the deprecated method names. Is this a good idea? Seems to work with no complaints in Xcode 6.x]

This works if your Deployment Target is 7.0 or greater. Category is `NSString (Util)`

## NSString+Util.h

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *) font;
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size;
```

## NSString+Util.m

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *) font {
    NSDictionary *fontAsAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:font};
    return [self sizeWithAttributes:fontAsAttributes];
}

- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size {
    NSDictionary *fontAsAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:font};
    CGRect retVal = [self boundingRectWithSize:size
                                     options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                  attributes:fontAsAttributes context:nil];
    return retVal.size;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier" size:16.0f];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: font,
                    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle };

CGRect textRect = [text boundingRectWithSize:size
                                 options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                              attributes:attributes
                                 context:nil];

CGSize size = textRect.size;
```

from two answers [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903304/replacement-for-deprecated-sizewithfontconstrainedtosizelinebreakmode-in-ios#answer-18961502) + [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948180/align-text-using-drawinrectwithattributes#answer-18949966)