# align text using drawInRect:withAttributes:

Tags: ios, nsstring, ios7

In the iOS 5 version of my app I had:

```
[self.text drawInRect: stringRect
             withFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"Courier" size: kCellFontSize]
        lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail
            alignment: NSTextAlignmentRight];
```

I'm upgrading for iOS 7. The above method is deprecated. I'm now using *drawInRect:withAttributes:*. The *attributes* parameter is an NSDictionary object. I can get *drawInRect:withAttributes:* to work for the former *font* parameter using this:

```
      UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"Courier" size: kCellFontSize];

      NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: font, NSFontAttributeName,
                                  nil];

      [self.text drawInRect: stringRect
             withAttributes: dictionary];
```

What key-value pairs do I add to *dictionary* to get *NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail* and *NSTextAlignmentRight*?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

There is one key to set the paragraph style of the text (including line breaking mode, text alignment, and more).

From [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011688-CH1-SW16):

> **`NSParagraphStyleAttributeName`**
>
> The value of this attribute is an `NSParagraphStyle` object. Use this attribute to apply multiple attributes to a range of text. If you do not specify this attribute, the string uses the default paragraph attributes, as returned by the `defaultParagraphStyle` method of `NSParagraphStyle`.

So, you can try the following:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier" size:kCellFontSize];

/// Make a copy of the default paragraph style
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
/// Set line break mode
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
/// Set text alignment
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: font,
                    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle };

[text drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attributes];
```

Comment: How did you find this? +1

Comment: While I can't figure a shorter variation - this certainly works, but seems like allot of work just to add some justification!

Comment: How can I make string multi line?

Answer (score 5):

The code is going that way:

```
CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(x, y, length-x, maxFontSize);
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier" size:maxFontSize];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;


   paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: font,
                                  NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
                                  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]};
[text drawInRect:textRect withAttributes:attributes];
```