# Convert sizeWithFont to iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using [a library for message cells in Obj-C](https://github.com/ppanopticon/PTSMessagingCell) and I'm bridging from Swift. Here are the 2 lines of code I'm trying to convert to iOS8 compatibility.

```
+(CGSize)messageSize:(NSString*)message {
return [message sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:messageTextSize] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake([PTSMessagingCell maxTextWidth], CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
}
```

and

```
CGSize dateSize = [self.timeLabel.text sizeWithFont:self.timeLabel.font forWidth:[PTSMessagingCell maxTextWidth] lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByClipping];
```

My attempt for both are as follows. I'm not a seasoned Obj-C coder, so go easy on me.

```
+(CGSize)messageSize:(NSString*)message {
return [message sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:PTSMessagingCell}];
}
```

and

```
CGSize dateSize = [self.timeLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:PTSMessagingCell}];
```

Are my attempts correct translations of the first 2 snippets?

Comment: But...what's your question?

Comment: Am I correct with my attempts to convert these?

Comment: You don't capture the linebreak modes, you need to use `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948180/align-text-using-drawinrectwithattributes

Comment: Also a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903304/replacement-for-deprecated-sizewithfontconstrainedtosizelinebreakmode-in-ios?lq=1