# Dynamic cell size

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, uipickerview

I have used

```
CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

and return `newHeight`;

to compute dynamic height of table cell. 
But in iOS 7 this is no more. So does iOS 7 has similar like this to compute dynamic height of cell or pickerview row height.

Updated Code:

NSString *text =str.text ;

```
                CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(320.0f, 40.0f);  // Make changes in width as per your label requirement.

                CGRect textRect = [text boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize
                                     options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                  attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:17]}
                                     context:nil];
                CGSize size = textRect.size;
                NSLog(@"textSize :: %f",size.height);


                return  size.height;
```

I want to set font size of text i am setting for picker view in following method.

```
 - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
NSString *title;
title=@"The Grand Bhagvati S G Highway";
return title;
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [deprecated in iOS 7 " sizeWithFont: constrainedToSize: lineBreakMode: " how can I replacement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903304/deprecated-in-ios-7-sizewithfont-constrainedtosize-linebreakmode-how-can)

Answer (score 2):

For IOS 7 calculate Size of text,You could try this:

```
      CGSize size = CGSizeMake(set_your_size);

     CGRect textRect = [text boundingRectWithSize:size
                             options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                          attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Helvetica"}
                             context:nil];

     CGSize textSize = textRect.size;
```

**EDIT:**

For more detail check this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011688-CH1-SW7

[ios-6-ios-7-transition](http://www.krisdigital.com/ios-6-ios-7-transition)

Comment: dhaval and @null I am getting textSize 0.0000 in my log.

Comment: may your "str.text" you pass it "null".check it proper....anyway it working proper in my application..

Comment: I want to set font size which i am passing to method titleforrow of pickerview...take a look at my updated code.

Comment: for more Check this : http://teilweise.tumblr.com/post/293948288 and https://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/john-szumski/ios-7-tutorial-series-dynamic-type

Answer (score 1):

You can use below:

```
CGRect textRect = [text boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize
                                     options:NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine|NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                  attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:cellFont}
                                     context:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use SizeToFit? create a label with a frame of the biggest frame you can give to a label and then use sizeToFit