# NSString sizeWithFont returns wrong values with font Georgia

Tags: ios, nsstring, uilabel

I am using Georgia and Georgia-Bold fonts in my app. Since it has to display a lot of text data that I download from server, I use NSString's method sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: extensively in various places of the app. Problem is, the values it returns are not quite right and letters like y, j and g are cut at the bottom. As you can see in this image

[image]

all "j"'s in last line don't fit in the label. Is it some known bug of sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:? More importantly, is there a way to work around this other than always adding i.e. 2 pixels to the label's height?

This is the line where I set the label size:

```
answerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(15, bottomOfRect(questionLabel.frame) + 10, frame.size.width - 45, [answer sizeWithFont:answerLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(frame.size.width - 45, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].height);
```

I double-checked to make sure that the label isn't outside bounds of its superview.

I am targeting iOS 6 and 7.

Comment: You are using a deprecated method if you are targeting for iOS 7. Maybe try the new one?

Comment: The most likely cause is that you're not adjusting correctly for the baseline, but it could also be a bug in the font (yes, fonts can have bugs; or they can sometimes just draw outside their boxes and claim it's a feature). First, can you explain how you're performing the drawing step (I suspect the error is there, especially if you're doing something like sizing a UILabel based on this value). But also check if the same bug occurs with other font families. And as others have hinted, let us know if you need pre-iOS7.

Comment: I updated the answer with additional info. And I didn't get this error on other font families I've checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
answerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(15, bottomOfRect(questionLabel.frame) + 10, frame.size.width - 45, ceilf([answer sizeWithFont:answerLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(frame.size.width - 45, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].height));
```

The issue is that `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` and the newer `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context` both return non-integral sizes, and you need to round them up to an integral size or minor clipping will occur, so use `ceilf()`

Answer (score 2):

Use `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` instead.
Look through this post for more details: [deprecated in iOS 7 “ sizeWithFont: constrainedToSize: lineBreakMode: ” how can I replacement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903304/deprecated-in-ios-7-sizewithfont-constrainedtosize-linebreakmode-how-can)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately I have to target iOS 6+.