# Return size of the cell for "cellForRowAtIndexPath" function?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

The cells for my table view can hold a maximum 140 characters, So for some cells in my UITableView the height will need to be slightly increased. I'm not looking for anything fancy, 140 characters would require the cell to be increased about twice its default height of 60.

I saw this stack overflow post:
[Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

and downloaded the iOS 7 sample project only to find 50+ unique functions which dynamically set the cell heights. Is this really necessary for the rare occasion of 140 character messages?

Can't I simply set set the cell height within this very function?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"chatCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSDictionary *message = self.messages[indexPath.row];

    UILabel *lblUsername=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UILabel *lblBody=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];

    lblUsername.text = [message valueForKeyPath:@"author"];
    lblBody.text = [message valueForKeyPath:@"body"];

    return cell;
}
```

I only need to implement an if statement like this:

```
if (lblBody.text.length <= 25) {
    // there's little text, keep the default height
} else if (lblBody.text.length <= 50) {
    // make the height of this cell slightly bigger
} else if (lblBody.text.length <= 75) {
    // make the height of this cell moderately bigger
} else {
    // make the height of this cell large
}
//etc...

return cell;
```

And thus the work for this part finished. Is this possible?

Comment: Not all characters are the same length. This problem is more complicated than you are expecting.

Comment: `heightForRowAtIndexPath` gets called BEFORE `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Changing the height in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will have no effect.

Comment: Using a prototype cell is simpler. Here's an example. http://www.macspotsblog.com/dynamic-uitableview-cell-heights-programmatically/

Answer (score 0):

You can set the row height in heightForRowAtIndexPath. Retrieve the text for that index path from your messages array and calculate the height. The code below resizes the height according to the label text.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat height = 0.0f;
    NSDictionary *message = self.messages[indexPath.row];
    NSString *text = [message valueForKeyPath:@"body"];
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    // MIN_CELL_HEIGHT in case you want a default height 
    height = MAX(size.height, MIN_CELL_HEIGHT); 

    return height;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to account for any padding the cell might have!

Comment: And adjust the label frame in cellForRowAtIndexPath by using [lblBody sizeToFit], otherwise it may be truncated.

Comment: I'm getting `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 7.0`

Comment: I don't know why Xcode is not complaining for me. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903304/replacement-for-deprecated-sizewithfontconstrainedtosizelinebreakmode-in-ios