# Strange behavior when trying to align vertically UILabel text

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm developing an iPhone app with latest SDK and XCode 4.2

I'm using this code to align vertically a text set it previously in an UILabel. Here is the code:

```
- (void)resizeLabel:(UILabel *)label
{
    CGSize maximumLabelSize = label.frame.size;

    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font 
                                      constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize 
                                          lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode]; 

    //adjust the label the the new height.
    CGRect newFrame = label.frame;
    NSLog(@"NumLines: %d, OldWidth: %f, NewWidth: %f, OldHeight: %f, newHeight: %f", label.numberOfLines, maximumLabelSize.width,  expectedLabelSize.width, maximumLabelSize.height, expectedLabelSize.height);
    newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
    label.frame = newFrame;
}
```

For text: **"Iglesia de la Merced"** I get:

```
NumLines: 2, OldWidth: 205.000000, NewWidth: 153.000000, OldHeight: 39.000000, newHeight: 21.000000
```

For text: **"Antiguo convento de los merdarios"** I get

```
NumLines: 2, OldWidth: 205.000000, NewWidth: 187.000000, OldHeight: 39.000000, newHeight: 42.000000
```

Both are set up to use two lines but **text is always drawn in one line only.**

Why am I getting double height when `expectedLabelSize.width` is smaller than `maximumLabelSize.width`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is wrapping in two lines, I guess.

from the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html):

> This method computes the metrics needed to draw the specified string. This method lays out the receiver’s text and attempts to make
>   it fit the specified size using the specified font and line break
>   options. During layout, the method may break the text onto multiple
>   lines to make it fit better. If the receiver’s text does not
>   completely fit in the specified size, it lays out as much of the text
>   as possible and truncates it (for layout purposes only) according to
>   the specified line break mode. It then returns the size of the
>   resulting truncated string. If the height specified in the size
>   parameter is less than a single line of text, this method may return a
>   height value that is bigger than the one specified.

Something to mention:
if you set numberOfLines to 0, it will automatically use as many lines as possible and needed.

Also try:

```
myUILabel.numberOfLines = 0;
myUILabel.text = @"Antiguo convento de los merdarios";
[myUILabel sizeToFit];
```

Comment: Yes, I set up for two lines in Interface Builder.

Comment: `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` does not care about what you do in nib-files. it just calculates, what is needed. and the second text needs 2 lines for the contained size (aka maximum size).

Comment: I have updated my question because as you can see both are set up to use two lines, but second one it is bigger.

Comment: my hint for numberOfLines is misleading. sorry. as explained above, `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:`does not take it in account. your numbers are just saying, that for the first string one line would be sufficient, while the second needs two.

Comment: you are getting the minimal bounding box.

Comment: I don't know why it needs two lines if expectedLabelSize.width is smaller than maximumLabelSize.width.

Comment: it is the width, AFTER it was breaker into 2 lines. and as you have break by words, it breaks before the word, that would be truncated.

Comment: By the way, I've forgotten to say that text is draw in one line only.

Comment: yeah, I know this happens. the method seems to be inaccurate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407106/why-is-sizewithfontconstrainedtosizelinebreakmode-returning-an-incorrect-size

Comment: what information made u accept the answer? I would like to point it out in the answer. thanks.

Comment: This one: stackoverflow.com/a/1304001/106435