# How to set UITextfield width dynamically?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitextfield

I have to make iPad application.

There are three questions `textfields`. I have to set width `UITextField` dynamically, `text` is coming from **webservice**. and I have to set `UITextField` width same as questions text..

when texts question size is small then `UITextField` size is small, 
when texts question size is large then `UITextField` size is large,

I have following code.....

```
txtQuestionOne.hidden=NO;
            txtQuestionTwo.hidden=NO;
            txtQuestionThree.hidden=NO;

            imgQueone.hidden=NO;
            imgQueTwo.hidden=NO;
            imgQueThree.hidden=NO;

            [txtQuestionOne setPlaceholder:[[appDelegate.questions objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"question"]];

            appDelegate.FirstQues =[[appDelegate.questions objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"question"];

            NSLog(@"current q1 %@", [[appDelegate.questions objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"question"]);


            if ([[[appDelegate.questions objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"permission"] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

                ratingButton1.hidden=NO;

                ratingLabel1.hidden=NO;
            }


            [txtQuestionTwo setPlaceholder:[[appDelegate.questions objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"question"]];

            appDelegate.SecondQues =[[appDelegate.questions objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"question"];

            NSLog(@"current q2 %@", [[appDelegate.questions objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"question"]);

            if ([[[appDelegate.questions objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"permission"] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

                ratingButton2.hidden=NO;

                ratingLabel2.hidden=NO;
            }


            [txtQuestionThree setPlaceholder:[[appDelegate.questions objectAtIndex:2] objectForKey:@"question"]];

            appDelegate.ThridQues =[[appDelegate.questions objectAtIndex:2] objectForKey:@"question"];

            NSLog(@"current q3 %@", [[appDelegate.questions objectAtIndex:2] objectForKey:@"question"]);

            if ([[[appDelegate.questions objectAtIndex:2] objectForKey:@"permission"] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

                ratingButton3.hidden=NO;

                ratingLabel3.hidden=NO;
            }
```

Please help me i dont know what can i do?

Comment: Why don't you use `UILabel` instead ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to get size for a NSString of specified font style. And use the returned CGSize to set size of UI element can be label, textfield.

```
 (comments from apple documentation)
// Single line, no wrapping. Truncation based on the UILineBreakMode.
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font; // Uses UILineBreakModeWordWrap
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font forWidth:(CGFloat)width lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode;

// for multi lined
// Wrapping to fit horizontal and vertical size. Text will be wrapped and truncated using the UILineBreakMode. If the height is less than a line of text, it may return
// a vertical size that is bigger than the one passed in.
// If you size your text using the constrainedToSize: methods below, you should draw the text using the drawInRect: methods using the same line break mode for consistency

- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size; // Uses UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode;
```

Eg:

```
NSString *valueString = @"This is example";
CGSize newSize = [valueString sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"TrebuchetMS" size: 12] ];

// assign new size
CGRect textFrame = textbox. frame;
textFrame. size  = newSize;
```

Comment: increase width of textfield and need to give the font size of
textfield. it is possible?

Comment: Yes. Above takes UIFont variable.. which takes Font Name and size

Comment: how can i use? please give me some example? i am new in iphone

Comment: Vote for right answers as it would help others who will seek answers in future

Answer (score 1):

did you try this

```
CGRect frame= yourTextField.frame;
frame.size.width=your_required_width;
yourTextField.frame=frame;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9132270/729763) post

It shows you the use of `sizeWithFont` which gives you a CGSize object from the size of your text. Then edit your textfields frame with the data of this CGSize object.