# UITextView disabling text selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextview

I'm having a hard time getting the `UITextView` to disable the selecting of the text.

I've tried:

```
canCancelContentTouches = YES;
```

I've tried subclassing and overwriting:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
```

(But that gets called only After the selection)

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view;
```

(I don't see that getting fired at all)

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldBegin:(NSSet *)touches
                 withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
             inContentView:(UIView *)view;
```

(I don't see that getting fired either)

What am I missing?

Comment: Since it's impossible to add answers to this: note the BEST answer here (IMHO) is actually a comment by Alexander: since iOS 7 there is a @property(nonatomic,getter=isSelectable) BOOL selectable NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0)

Comment: I got the question reopened and added `selectable` as a proper answer. Yay!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Issue [How disable Copy, Cut, Select, Select All in UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426731) has a workable solution to this that I've just implemented and verified:

Subclass `UITextView` and overwrite `canBecomeFirstResponder:`

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return NO;
}
```

Note that this disables links and other tappable text content.

Comment: If you don't want any user interaction at all, yes.

Comment: good point. However it also disables the input cursor. Is there a way of allowing the cursor, but not allowing text selection?

Comment: You can also avoid the subclassing step and just use a category in the same UIViewController where your UITextView lives. (I wouldn't bet on this working forever though) (a)implementation UITextView (NoSelection) - (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder { return NO; } (a)end

Comment: Have you tried to use the property selectable?

@property(nonatomic,getter=isSelectable) BOOL selectable NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0); // toggle selectability, which controls the ability of the user to select content and interact with URLs & attachments

Comment: That's very useful, @Alexander - thanks! canBecomeFirstResponder is still a good solution if you need to target iOS versions prior to 7, though.

Comment: This disables links, etc.

Comment: A good point. In my case, I wanted links disabled, so I wasn't too fussed about that.

Comment: Anyone know of a solution that does not disable links but does disable highlighting? I tried overriding long-press but that seems to disable link tapping as well...

Comment: @TrespassersW overwrite - (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView and set textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0); can accomplish this

Comment: seems like in iOS 10, this code disable selection and keep links & scrolling working at same time

Comment: Even when disabling selection, user can still long-press and 'drag away' the url. In cases where this was meant to act as a button (and the URL, private), this behavior sure hammers in the final nail.

Answer (score 47):

I've found that calling

```
[textView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

works quite well.

Comment: This will also disable the scrolling feature on UITextView

Comment: And disable the ability to click links

Comment: I use the uitextview as a subview in a custom uitableviewcell. 
It works like a dream

Answer (score 21):

`UITextView`'s [`selectable`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/selectable) property:

> This property controls the ability of the user to select content and
>   interact with URLs and text attachments. The default value is YES.

Comment: It seems like there is no setter in objective-C?

Comment: `-[UITextView isSelectable]`:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618627-selectable?language=objc

Comment: That looks like just the `get` - I'm seeing compiler errors when trying to set? `textView.isSelectable = NO;`

Comment: That's because `-isSelectable` is the name of the getter only. Use `-[UITextView setSelectable:]` to set it. With property syntax, both the getter and setter are `selectable`.

`BOOL foo = textView.selectable;` or `textView.selectable = bar;`

Comment: This one also disables links

Answer (score 15):

**Swift 4**, **Xcode 10**

This solution will

- disable highlighting
- enable tapping links
- allow scrolling

Make sure you set the delegate to YourViewController

```
yourTextView.delegate = yourViewControllerInstance
```

Then

```
extension YourViewController: UITextViewDelegate {

    func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            textView.selectedTextRange = nil
        } else {
            view.endEditing(true)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It does not work for me in iOS 13.
Instead of `view.endEditing(true)` use `textView.selectedTextRange = nil`

Comment: @EvgenyKarev Please add your comment as an answer.

Comment: if you use it on UITableViewCell then write contentView.endEditing(true) instead of view.endEditing(true)

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 4, Xcode 10:**

If you want to make it so the user isn't able to select or edit the text.

This makes it so it can not be edited:

```
textView.isEditable = false
```

This disables all user interaction:

```
textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

This makes it so that you can't select it. Meaning it will not show the edit or paste options. I think this is what you are looking for.

```
textView.isSelectable = false
```

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like what you actually want is a giant UILabel inside a UIScrollView, and not a UITextView.

update: if you are on newer versions of iOS UILabel now has a lines property:

[Multiple lines of text in UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990221/multiple-lines-of-text-in-uilabel)

Comment: Yea I guess.  Will be the next thing I do if I don't figure this out.

Comment: thanx dude, I don't know about dizy, but I actually needed a UILabel.

Comment: UILabel will prevent the line-breaks. You want a UITextView with no user interaction enabled... and then you want that inside of a UIScrollView. 
Alternatively, you could display a transparent UIWebView with your text in a textView in the UIWebView (just use loadHTML to import your text/code into the UIWebView (including the CSS code to make the background transparent) then you can use javascript to make it not selectable but still scrollable).

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw I don't think your first sentence is correct. A quick Google seems to indicate that UILabel supports line breaks just fine.

Comment: @MarkAmery Wow! I never knew! UILabel has a "lines" property that is on "1" by default... so if you put in multiple lines nothing will happen, you have to modify the "lines" property to a higher number to support multiple lines! Neat :)

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Don't make it higher - set it to 0 instead, and then you can have as many lines as you like.

Comment: @MarkAmery you just made my day! Thankyou for the tip, that helps so much with future projects! Haha! :) +1

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to prevent it from being edited, then set the UITextView's "editable" property to NO/False.

If you're trying to leave it editable but not selectable, that's going to be tricky. You might need to create a hidden textview that the user can type into and then have UITextView observe that hidden textview and populate itself with the textview's text.

Comment: This is what I did for a non editable / selected text field:

    class

Answer (score 3):

To do this first subclass the UITextView

and in the implementation do the following

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(nullable UIEvent *)event
{
    self.selectable = NO;
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(nullable NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(nullable UIEvent *)event
{
        self.selectable = YES;
 }
```

this should work fine,

Comment: This disables links too

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting userInteractionEnabled to NO for your UITextView? But you'd lose scrolling too.

If you need scrolling, which is probably why you used a UITextView and not a UILabel, then you need to do more work.  You'll probably have to override `canPerformAction:withSender:` to return `NO` for actions that you don't want to allow:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    switch (action) {
        case @selector(paste:):
        case @selector(copy:):
        case @selector(cut:):
        case @selector(cut:):
        case @selector(select:):
        case @selector(selectAll:):
        return NO;
    }
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

For more, [UIResponderStandardEditActions](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponderStandardEditActions_Protocol/UIResponderStandardEditActions.html#//apple_ref/occ/cat/UIResponderStandardEditActions) .

Comment: I mentioned that I already tried that :)  canPerform doesn't get called until after you make the selection

Comment: Downvote: this won't prevent the cut/copy/define toolbar from appearing - there are better solutions listed on this page.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable text selection by subclassing `UITextView`.

The below solution is:

- compatible with isScrollEnabled
- compatible with loupe/magnifier
- but not compatible with links ([see here for a solution compatible with links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49443814/1033581))

```swift
/// Class to disallow text selection
/// while keeping support for loupe/magnifier and scrolling
/// https://stackoverflow.com/a/49428248/1033581
class UnselectableTextView: UITextView {

    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        // prevents selection from loupe/magnifier (_UITextSelectionForceGesture), multi tap, tap and a half, etc.
        // without losing the loupe/magnifier or scrolling
        // but we lose taps on links
        addSubview(transparentOverlayView)
    }
    let transparentOverlayView: UIView = {
        $0.backgroundColor = .clear
        $0.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        return $0
    }(UIView())
    override var contentSize: CGSize {
        didSet {
            transparentOverlayView.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: contentSize)
        }
    }

    // required to prevent blue background selection from any situation
    override var selectedTextRange: UITextRange? {
        get { return nil }
        set {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For swift, there is a property called "isSelectable" and its by default assign to true

you can use it as follow:

```
textView.isSelectable = false
```