# Disable Cut and Copy in UITextView even after allowing the user to edit the text

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How disable Copy, Cut, Select, Select All in UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426731/how-disable-copy-cut-select-select-all-in-uitextview)

I have a `UITextView` which can be edited. I have another button for "Copy", so I want to disable the built-in "Copy" and "Cut" features of the text view.
These are shown as a black mini popover when double tapping inside the text view. Is there any way to block only these two options and still let the user edit the text?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639485/uitextview-disabling-text-selection

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426731/how-disable-copy-cut-select-select-all-in-uitextview

Answer (score 6):

overrides the `canPerformAction:withSender:` method to return `NO` for actions that you don't want to allow:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
    {
        if (action == @selector(paste:))
            return NO;
        if (action == @selector(select:))   
            return NO;   
        if (action == @selector(selectAll:))   
            return NO;  
        return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
    }
```

**Another way**

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    if (menuController) {
        [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Also check [This link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: First snippet works fine in the UITextView's subclass which I've created. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Subclass `UITextView` and overwrite `canBecomeFirstResponder`:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return NO;
}
```

Hope this helps you..

Comment: -1, this answer is wrong. This makes the text view uneditable. The OP explicitly asked for a solution that leaves the text view editable.