# How To append CRLF in my UILABEL

Tags: iphone

I am displaying text on a UILABEL from XML, I am getting CRLF's in the text.So i am not able to append the new lines for my label.This is the code i tried.But iam not getting
PLease help me in this

```
             NSArray* array = [subHead.Description componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r\n"];
    NSLog(@"Count : %d",[array count]);
     for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
     {
        NSLog(@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:i]);
         NSString* s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:i]];
        // s = [s stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet controlCharacterSet]];
         if ([s length]>0){
             [str appendString:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
             [str appendString:@"\r\n"];flag++;
         }else {
             NSLog(@"Two \n\'s  are occured");
         }

         NSLog(@"Flag value : %d",flag);

    }

    NSLog(@"String : %@",str);
    NSLog(@"Description : %@",subHead.Description);
    subheadlabel.text=str;
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0):

set yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

follow [How to add line break for UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312899/how-to-add-line-break-for-uilabel) link you will get idea how it works.

This should help you.