# iOS: New line characters doesn't recognised in data received from server

Tags: ios, nsstring

I am downloading string data from the server. Data contains new line characters `"\n"` and when I assigned string to `Label`'s text property, the new line characters printed as `"\n"` rather than having new line between lines. If I have same string stored locally, it works fine! I am getting UTF8 strings. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your UILabel creation

```
label.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Hope this helps you..

Comment: That was strange. I had "\n" on my server string but it was reading "\\n"!!! I had to do [myLabelText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@"\n"] as mentioned on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312899/how-to-add-line-break-for-uilabel