# How to add two lines of strings into a same UILabel

Tags: ios, ios7, uilabel

I want to insert 2 lines for a `UILabel`like this

> $2500.50
>
> per ride

I need to add these two lines into a same `UILabel`programmatically. How can I do that. Please anybody help me.

Thanks

Comment: u can use @"$2500.50\nper ride" like this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312899/how-to-add-line-break-for-uilabel

Comment: Yes, use escape character \n. As mentioned by @CoolMonster

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved like so:

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

// allows the UILabel to wrap text across multiple lines
myLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

// allows the UILabel to display an unlimited number of lines
myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

You can add line breaks to the text using new-line characters (“\n”), as mentioned in the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to set some properties like this

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[myLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 300, 200)];
myLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
myLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

[myLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", @"$2500.50", @"per ride"]];

[self.view addSubview:myLabel];
```