# multiple line of UILabel, is it possible?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uilabel

I've read through SO and it seems that it is possible, however I tried it and it didn't work out:

```
UILabel * detailed_label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, labelSize.height + 30, textSize.width + 5, textSize.height + 5)];
    detailed_label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    detailed_label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    detailed_label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    detailed_label.text = self.detailed;
    detailed_label.numberOfLines = 0;
    detailed_label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    detailed_label.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    detailed_label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
    CGSize detailedLabelSize = [self.detailed sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];


    UIButton *v = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    v.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, textSize.width + avatar_image.size.width + 10, labelSize.height + detailedLabelSize.height + 30);
    //label.center = CGPointMake(v.frame.size.width / 2, v.frame.size.height / 2);
    [v addSubview:detailed_label];
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I had a look at your code and you're assigning a width at the UILabel which is textSize.width+5. Is this textSize.width related to the UILabel text?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990221/multiple-lines-of-text-in-uilabel

Comment: Can you try a bigger height to label ? For example, 2*textSize.height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your working with a UIButton. You can take advantage of the label already on it, use `button.titleLabel` to access it.

Next set `button.titleLabel.minimumFontSize` and `button.titleLabel.font`. Then set `button.titleLabel.numberOfLines` > 1.

If you need to find out how high to make your label. Use `[self.detailed sizeWithFont:fontWithMinimumFontSize constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, DBL_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].height + PADDING;`