# how to display text in new line

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i wan to display the string line by line...what changes i shd make in the below code..

i want the result to display like this

for example-

```
latest loan:0000
conytry:abc
amount:000
```

the below code is not working for new line...so what change i shd make in the below code

// code

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Latest loan: %@ \n country:  %@ \n amount $%.2f",
                  name,country,outstandingAmount];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't touch that code :-@. Just set,

```
label.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990221/multiple-lines-of-text-in-uilabel)