# IOS: I cannot show my label multiline

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have a problem with UILabel. I want to show the comments multiline. But they are single line. This is my code:

```
CGRect currentFrame = comment.frame;
CGSize max = CGSizeMake(comment.frame.size.width,20000.0f);
CGSize expected = [comment.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0] constrainedToSize:max lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
currentFrame.size.height = expected.height;
comment.frame = currentFrame;
comment.numberOfLines = 0;
[comment sizeToFit];
```

But the result is not good. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Are you setting the UILabel to a 10pt font size to be consistent with your expected height?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990221/multiple-lines-of-text-in-uilabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is okay, but you should add this line in your code to get multi line

```
comment.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should increase the number of lines like

```
comment.numberOfLines = 2  /* or more */
```

So when the text size increase the width of label it will be multy line but keep in mind about font size and lable size ration

Comment: As I know, comment.numberOfLines = 0 means there is no limit with the lines. So that is what I need. I cannot do that.