# Text not displaying on UILabel when the text is too large.

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a text (Story of a book). I am taking UILabel to display it. But it is not showing me on view. I am using the following code:

```
    CGSize labelsize;
    UILabel *commentsTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];;
    [commentsTextLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    commentsTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [commentsTextLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [commentsTextLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ACaslonPro-Regular"size:17]];
    labelsize=[story sizeWithFont:commentsTextLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(280, 15000) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    commentsTextLabel.frame=CGRectMake(20, 200, 280, labelsize.height);
   commentsTextLabel.text = story;// more than 1000 lines

   [self.view addSubview:commentsTextLabel];
```

When i debug my code, i found  labelsize.height is coming out in my case 13145.Still it is not showing.
If i descrease  15000 to 11000 , then text is showing on view with .... at last.

labelsize=[story sizeWithFont:commentsTextLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(280, 15000) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

Please help me out.
Thanks

Comment: why dont you use UITextView....?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use non-editable UITextView? Otherwise, try setting MAXFLOAT as height constraint when calculating label size.

Comment: here what is labelsize means what type of variable?

Comment: I dont want to use scrolling in some part, my requirement is to scroll whole view.thats why i am not using UITextView.

Comment: I debug that with some lesser text labelsize.height is correct.Can anyone please implement this at your end ?

Comment: Try setting the height constraint to CGFloatMax

Comment: I just tried MAXFLOAT and CGFLOAT_MAX , both are not working.

Comment: After this line  [self.view addSubview:commentsTextLabel];  add another line [commentsTextLabel sizeToFit]; and check

Comment: once check my answer may be it helps you.

Comment: [commentsTextLabel sizeToFit];  also not working, My problem is label is not showing on view at all when text is so large.

Comment: put the line commentsTextLabel.text = story; before labelsize=[story sizeWithFont:commentsTextLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(280, 15000) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

Comment: This is also not working. Please anybody try this code at your end :(

Comment: It is advised to use UITextView, when the amount of data to display is in large size instead of UILabel..

Comment: You need to use UITextView with scrolling enabled and editable/selected disabled (instead of UIScrollView & Content view & UILabel).

Answer (score 13):

`UILabel` will render all its text at once into a backing buffer. iOS devices only have a limited amount of graphics memory to do this work, so it will fail once the graphics data goes above a certain size.

For large amounts of text you should use Core Text or something like `UITextView` which renders its text on-demand much more efficiently.

Comment: I give faith. I had the same issue and solved it using several `UILabels` together. When I tried it in an iPad 2, it ran out of memory and the app crashed.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same thing lately, the UILabel size is allocated correctly, it's just the UILabel itself cannot hold too many characters, the maximum character limit depends on font and font size.

For the font I used, the limit is around 13k characters. My work around is to truncate the string before hand, it's not ideal though.

Comment: mem is still something to be concerned about, so truncating is wise.

Comment: UILabel will render everything at once into a backing buffer. iOS devices only have a limited amount of graphics memory to do this work, so it looks like it's failing after a certain amount of data. Use core text or something like UITextView which are designed to draw their contents more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add test wrapping to the label or it will flow off the edges.

```
self.label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    CGSize labelsize;
    UILabel *commentsTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];;
    [commentsTextLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    commentsTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    commentsTextLabel.text = @"The sediment-free enrichment (3) was cultivated anaerobically either in a mineral medium as described previously (19) with yeastextract (0.5%) as a carbon source or in autoclaved (1218C for 40 min) spentenrichment culture medium adjusted to pH 8.3 with sterile anaerobic 2 N NaOH.The spent culture medium was obtained by centrifugation (with anaerobic centrifuge tubes) of the enrichment culture grown in 0.5% yeast extract medium.The pH was kept within 8.0 to 8.5 by adjustment with anaerobic sterile 2 NNaOH. D. dehalogenans JW/IU-DC1 was grown in the base medium describedpreviously (19) supplemented as indicated in the text at 378C and pH 7.5.";
    [commentsTextLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [commentsTextLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ACaslonPro-Regular"size:17]];
    labelsize=[commentsTextLabel.text sizeWithFont:commentsTextLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(280, 15000) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    commentsTextLabel.frame=CGRectMake(20, 200, 280, labelsize.height);
        [self.view addSubview:commentsTextLabel];
```

Comment: this code is working for small text i know , But why this is not working for very large text?

Answer (score 0):

If u want to display more than 1000 lines of text then its better to use UITextView instead of Uilabel. you can use the following code for UITextView

```
UITextView *commentsTextLabel = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    commentsTextLabel.frame=CGRectMake(20, 20, 280,100);
    commentsTextLabel.text = story;
    commentsTextLabel.editable=NO;
    commentsTextLabel.scrollEnabled=YES;
    //commentsTextLabel.numberOfLines=1;
    commentsTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    //[commentsTextLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    //[commentsTextLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]];
    commentsTextLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
    commentsTextLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:commentsTextLabel];
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score -2):

you can put multiple lines of text in UILabel to solve your issue.

```
textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

Courtesy:-https://stackoverflow.com/a/990244/1865424

It may help you.