# Long text in UILabel inside UIScrollView not displayed

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uilabel, long-integer

Here is my view hierarchy:

[image: taken from Debug view hierarchy]

The second label has a very long text (~17k characters). Although it is rendered in the view hierarchy debugger, the long label is not rendered in simulator when running the project.
It takes up the space, because the scroll view does scroll.
[image]

I've put together a small sample project: [Github project](https://github.com/mihai-moldovan/UIScrollViewLongLabel)

**UPDATE**
It can be only reproduced on the Simulator.
I tested it on an iPhone 6 with iOS 10.2 and the label renders correctly.

Nevertheless, is there any chance that it may appear on a real device?

Comment: I ran your project and got scrolling, debug View Hierarchy when running, it showed correct text but it is not displayed on simulator.

Comment: Exactly my findings. I have no idea why it is not displayed on the simulator. Maybe it's a simulator bug

Comment: Try to read this article, Mike Weller's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764402/text-not-displaying-on-uilabel-when-the-text-is-too-large

Comment: Thanks. So I guess this is a duplicate issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text not displaying on UILabel when the text is too large.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764402/text-not-displaying-on-uilabel-when-the-text-is-too-large)