# UILabel cannot render too many words

Tags: ios, uilabel

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.
Over 6000 Chinese,UILabel is blanked but it has content.In other word UILabel cannot render too manny words.
How can i solove it ?

Comment: As @Mike Weller mentioned, you should use UITextView for displaying too long text instead of UILabel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764402/text-not-displaying-on-uilabel-when-the-text-is-too-large

Comment: it is no use.The label or textView is in a cell. When the words are less than 6000, label is normal.  Actually,I don't need a scrollview.

Comment: You can set `textView.scrollEnabled = NO` for disable scroll.

Comment: when you say the label or textView is in a cell, is this a table view or collection cell?  And when you say you do not need a scrollview, what do you think the user wants to see instead?  All 6000 characters in one (big, massive, gigantic, spilling-off-the-screen) cell?

Comment: a post. The first section shows author info , novel and images. The second section offer support operation and other operation. The last section is comment. So, even if i use the textview, i need to show all the text in the textview , other than showing text when scrolls . Doing so, textview is the same with label. Now , I want to cut the text in pieces....

Answer (score 0):

I try to use core data to render large text only in one view, but it has no use. So I will use a few cells to show those word. And what I need to do is cut the large text in pieces. I think it is better for performance than using only one cell.