# Setting attributedText of UILabel causing issue with Lengthier content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsattributedstring

In my project I want to add an attributed text in UILabel placed on the xib.
It's working perfectly, but if large text appears it shows some issues.

#### My current implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _demoLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    _demoLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    _demoLabel.attributedText = [self demoNameWithFontSize:21 andColor:[UIColor redColor]];

}

- (NSMutableAttributedString *)demoNameWithFontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize andColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = nil;
    NSString *demoName = @"Blah blah blah";
    UIFont  *demoFont  = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Zapfino" size:fontSize];
    attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:demoName];
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraph = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraph.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    [attributedText addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraph range:NSMakeRange(0, [demoName length])];
    [attributedText addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:demoFont range:NSMakeRange(0, [demoName length])];
    [attributedText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:color range:NSMakeRange(0, [demoName length])];

    return attributedText;
}
```

### Output:

[image: Zapfino]

### Issue:

It is not displaying the whole text, even if I applied the `NSMutableParagraphStyle`.
How can I solve this ?

### Alternative I found:

If I change

```
UIFont  *demoFont  = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Zapfino" size:fontSize];
```

to

```
UIFont  *demoFont  = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize];
```

It'll work and gives output like:

[image: System]

But the issue is I need to use custom font, can't use default font. Also cannot change the font size.

I checked UILabel class reference and googled, but couldn't find a solution. Please help me.
Is there anyway to span this text into multiple lines ?

Comment: Do you mean you want the font to shrink when there is too much text to fit? Your question is not clear.

Comment: @LeoNatan Spanning text into multiple lines is most suitable solution for me (Because I can't reduce the font size)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990221/multiple-lines-of-text-in-uilabel

Comment: @Catalyst: I know that, that won't work here. First check my code, second I'm using attributedText property of UILabel not text property. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: It works when you increase the height of the label.

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize the UILabel to fit the text.

You can calculate the size with the `boundingRectWithSize:options:context:` `NSAttributedString` class method, which takes an attributed string and calculates the size within a set rect based on all the attributes of the string.