# how can set the label text Attributed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

how can set the label text Attributed so that the text shown on other line..
My Code

```
clickLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(27, 340, 300, 95)];
clickLabel.attributedText=@"Click on Done,You agree to accept Terms and  Conditions and Privacy Policy of Ios App";
clickLabel.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];
UIFont *boldFont2 = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
[clickLabel setFont:boldFont2];
[scrollView addSubview:clickLabel];
```

Comment: What part of the text should be on a new line?

Comment: Terms And conditions

Comment: clickLabel.attributedText=@"Click on Done,You agree to accept \nTerms and  Conditions and Privacy Policy of Ios App";
use \n where you want to start new line

Comment: have you set numberOflines 2 and why you are using attributed string just use simple string and insert \n where you want to break line

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple lines of text in UILabel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990221/multiple-lines-of-text-in-uilabel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For new line use \n and set numberOfLines more than 1 as follows

```
clickLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(27, 340, 300, 95)];
clickLabel.attributedText=@"Click on Done,You agree to accept \n Terms and  Conditions and Privacy Policy of Ios App";
clickLabel.numberOfLines  = 2;
clickLabel.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];
UIFont *boldFont2 = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
[clickLabel setFont:boldFont2];
[scrollView addSubview:clickLabel];
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this solution?

```
clickLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(27, 340, 300, 95)];

clickLabel.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Click on Done,You agree to accept\nTerms and Conditions and Privacy Policy of Ios App" attributes:nil] ;

clickLabel.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];

clickLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

UIFont *boldFont2 = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
[clickLabel setFont:boldFont2];
[scrollView addSubview:clickLabel];
```

Answer (score 0):

To show in multiple lines use `\n` and `numberOfLines`

```
clickLabel.text = @"Click on Done, You agree to accept\nTerms and  Conditions and Privacy Policy of iOS App";
clickLabel.numberOfLines = 0; // 0 mean any number of lines
```

Comment: Because it does not show properly ... text is too long here

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
NSMutableAttributedString* attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"YOUR_STRING"];

clickLabel.attributedText = attrStr;
```

and do both :

- `clickLabel.numberOfLines = 2;`
- add \n before your words.

Answer (score 0):

Its working, set appropriate height for the clickLabel.

```
UILabel * clickLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(27, 340, 300, 100)];
clickLabel.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Click on Done,You agree to accept\nTerms and Conditions and Privacy Policy of Ios App" attributes:nil] ;
clickLabel.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];
clickLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
UIFont *boldFont2 = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
[clickLabel setFont:boldFont2];
[self.view addSubview:clickLabel];
```