# Objective c label.numberOflines is not working

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

No matter I set the number of lines to 0 or to 100, it just won't change and the texts remain ... at the end. I've tried NSLineBreakByWordWrapping but it just removed the ... and do nothing.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[cell.contentView addSubview:label];
label.text = myString;
label.frame = CGRectMake(17, 42, 200, 30);
[label sizeToFit];
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
label.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Comment: I've changed but it still does not work.

Comment: please find answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990221/multiple-lines-of-text-in-uilabel ...

Comment: What do you mean by not working? _This property controls the maximum number of lines to use in order to fit the label’s text into its bounding rectangle._

Comment: You should write `label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
label.numberOfLines = 0;` above `[sizeToFit]`