# Set height of label

Tags: ios, objective-c, responsive, textlabel

To make my app more responsive I want to set the height of my label to expand it over the full cell.

It's now this: https://blazor.nl/uploads/get/cd6a93c852623266882afce5b480b804/IMG-0296

How can I do this?

My label is `cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.alerts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];`

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple lines of text in UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990221/multiple-lines-of-text-in-uilabel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the number of rows 0.

```
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Comment: It works, but the data only shows on a swipe. How can I fix that?

Comment: Nvm, it seems that I have to wait a little longer.