# Increase Label Editor Limit Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, label

I have very large amount of text characters that I am setting on a label with attributed text property in storyboard. However, it looks like the number of characters it allows is limited because I have been restricted to a certain amount.

I have already set lines of text to 0, which means that the number of lines should be unlimited. However, that did not work for me.

Is there a way I can increase the editor height so I can edit more characters? Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990221/multiple-lines-of-text-in-uilabel/37430979

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple lines of text in UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990221/multiple-lines-of-text-in-uilabel)

Comment: none of these solved my issue.

Comment: I want to increase the height of the text editor on the right panel so all my text could be visible for editing

Comment: Editing? You are dealing with `UILabel` or `UITextView` (or even `UITextField`)?
Could you provide some screenshots of your application?