# How do I add new line in a UILabel inside a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uilabel

I would like to have the **bookSummary** in a new line.

this is my current code, which sets a `UILabel` inside a `UITableViewCell`:

`cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(books[indexPath.row].bookAuthor ?? "") - \(books[indexPath.row].bookSummary ?? "")"`

[image: UI Interface]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple lines of text in UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990221/multiple-lines-of-text-in-uilabel)

Comment: I have tried it but I still couldn't get on how to apply it in the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\n` as you are using in your string.
and set the `numberOfLines` equal to `0` on the `detailTextLabel`

```
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(books[indexPath.row].bookAuthor ?? "") \n \(books[indexPath.row].bookSummary ?? "")"

cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
```