# Finding text's bounding rect in Core Text

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, macos, core-text

I'm trying to find the boundaries of a line of text in Core Text. For simplicity, assume it has a single character.
At the moment I'm using the following method:

```
line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(attrString);
rect = CTLineGetImageBounds(line, context);
```

It works most of the times, but for some characters, like math italic d (Unicode: 0x1D451) or math italic q (Unicode: 0x1D45E), the width is a bit short.

I tried using `CTLineGetTypographicBounds()` or `CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints`, but they didn't help either (I think they use glyph's advance to find the width, not its graphical width.) As the font itself isn't italic, I also can't use slant angle to correct this.

I tried accessing the glyphs directly and using `CTFontCreatePathForGlyph()`, but failed as CGGlyph and UniChar are both 16-bits and I need 32-bit characters.

Does anyone know if I'm doing anything wrong? If so, what's the right way?

**Update:**

To make sure it's not a problem related to the font, I used different fonts. The problem exists even for ASCII characters in Arial Italic.

**Update:**

Ignore my previous update! It turns out this one (problem with Arial Italic) was my own bug. The first problem still stands though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the bug report I made, apparently this is a CoreText problem, appearing in rare cases. Will let you know as soon as I find a fix.

**Update: March 15 '12**

I forgot to update this sooner, but this is fixed. The fix is in OS X Lion / iOS 5.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, `CTLineGetImageBounds` is the correct function to use. I suggest filing a bug report in [RadarWeb](https://bugreport.apple.com/).

Comment: I just filed a bug. Will let you know if I hear anything.