# CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints does not limit result to constrain size

Tags: core-text

I use the CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints function to define the size, my attributed string will need, but the height I get is smaller than it should be and also the width is bigger than the constrainSize.width parameter. Here is my code:

```
CTTextAlignment textAlignment = kCTLeftTextAlignment;
CTLineBreakMode lineBreakMode = kCTLineBreakByWordWrapping;

CTParagraphStyleSetting paragraphSettings[] = {
    {
        kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierAlignment,
        sizeof(textAlignment),
        &textAlignment
    },
    {
        kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierLineBreakMode,
        sizeof(lineBreakMode),
        &lineBreakMode
    }  
};

CTParagraphStyleRef paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(paragraphSettings, sizeof(paragraphSettings) / sizeof(paragraphSettings[0]));

NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[authorString stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@", bodyText]] autorelease];

CTFontRef ctfontAuthor = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)@"Arial-BoldMT", 14.0, NULL);
CTFontRef ctfontBody = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)@"Arial", 14.0, NULL);
[attrString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName value:(id)paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [attrString length])];
[attrString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName value:(id)ctfontAuthor range:NSMakeRange(0, [authorString length] + 1)];
[attrString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName value:(id)ctfontBody range:NSMakeRange([authorString length] + 1, [bodyText length])];
CFRelease(ctfontAuthor);
CFRelease(ctfontBody);
CFRelease(paragraphStyle);

CFRange fitRange;
CGSize result = CGSizeZero;
CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFMutableAttributedStringRef)attrString);
result = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, [authorString length] + [bodyText length] + 1), NULL, size, &fitRange);
CFRelease(framesetter);
return result;// result is the value I need to be constrained to size (229.0, MAXFLOAT) but sometimes it is 231 and some more
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem, and I found the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10019378/1313863) (at least for the height problem). You need to specify a kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierLineSpacingAdjustment.

Comment: probably that's right for another cases, but doesn't work for me. Height I receive from method differs from needed height for the lineHeight value but not the line spacing value.

Answer (score 0):

Before returning result size try to set result.width parameter to the width from your constraints size.

Answer (score 0):

I also run in this case, solved it and wrote a category, which works for me in all cases. See my answer in If you use zero as height, it does not restrict the height to any height. I wrote a category for this issue, which works for me in all cases. See [iOS UITableView with dynamic text and images rendered together (NSAttributedString + images)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586190/ios-uitableview-with-dynamic-text-and-images-rendered-together-nsattributedstri/22104529#22104529)