# CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints returns wrong height

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-text

i know there are posts about this, but none of them suggests something useful.. So my problem is that CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints returns height that is too small for my text, the longer the text the more of it get's cut. Code that i use to calculate height:

```
CGFloat widthConstraint = self.frame.size.width;
CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attrString);
CGSize suggestedSize = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(framesetter,CFRangeMake(0, 0),NULL,CGSizeMake(widthConstraint, 20000),NULL);
CGFloat suggestedHeight = suggestedSize.height;
```

So my question is what choise do i have? Maybe there are some workarounds? 
One of the solutions that i have found is to draw the text and only then find the height, but i don't know how to do that. So maybe someone has some solution to this?

Thanks i advance!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints sometimes returns incorrect size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374591/ctframesettersuggestframesizewithconstraints-sometimes-returns-incorrect-size)

Comment: its similar but I am asking if somebody found a decision to this, in yout posted linkt there's only suggestion to draw text and only then get the height.. But that is my problem i don't know how and asking for some help :) Some tutorial or maybe an idea of how to do it. Some guidance because i am stuck :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a very long time i've finally found out what's wrong.. After all the method works as intended and i think everyone else that says it's not on the internet have made some mistakes.. My mistake was when i draw text i've left some bad hardcoded values.. So if anyone has issues with CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints, double or tripple check your drawing code!

Comment: I also suspected CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints was at fault. In my case my attributed string had a font height of zero points. Check your fonts people!

Comment: my font size is coronet. Yet my method is working for font size upto 18 but if I increase more then the height is not sufficient.

Comment: My issue was measuring using CTFrameSetter but then having old draw code using [NSString drawInRect:...] instead of the CTFrameSetter to draw