# Using CFArrayGetValueAtIndex in Swift with UnsafePointer (AUPreset)

Tags: swift, core-audio, core-foundation

My problem is simple, but tricky. I want to write this line

```
AUPreset *aPreset = (AUPreset*)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(mEQPresetsArray, indexPath.row);
```

in Swift. The trick is that the return value is `UnsafePointer<Void>`.

Comment: `let aPreset = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(mEQPresetsArray, indexPath.row) as AUPreset`

Comment: The best way by far is to convert the CFArray to NSArray and go from there.

Comment: @PhuDuy It is not posible to cast from UnsafePointer<Void> to AUPreset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?:

```
    let aPreset = UnsafePointer<AUPreset>(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(mEQPresetsArray, indexPath.row))
```

Comment: With this expression I don't get a valid AUPreset object.

Comment: @Vanya, `AUPreset` is not an object type. It's C-struct and imported as Swift struct.

Comment: OK, sorry SWIFT struct, but when I use "aPreset.memory" with this expression, I do get a AUPreset struct. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the Swift 4 version

```
let aPreset = unsafeBitCast(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(mEQPresetsArray, indexPath), to: AUPreset.self)
```