# UILabel height?

Tags: iphone, height, uilabel

I have an uilabel setup with IB and with this code:

```
// setup label
sv.text =  @"When in the Course of human events, it becomes necessary for one people to dissolve the political bands which have connected them with another, and to assume among the powers of the earth, the separate and equal station to which the Laws of Nature and of Nature's God entitle them, a decent respect to the opinions of mankind requires that they should declare the causes which impel them to the separation.When in the Course of human events, it becomes necessary for one people to dissolve the political bands which have connected them with another, and to assume among the powers of the earth, the separate and equal station to which the Laws of Nature and of Nature's God entitle them, a decent respect to the opinions of mankind requires that they should declare the causes which impel them to the separation."; 
sv.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap; 
sv.numberOfLines = 0;
[sv sizeToFit];
```

my question is, how do I get the uilabel height?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446405/adjust-uilabel-height-depending-on-the-text

Comment: duplicate try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61887135/6314955

Answer (score 4):

Try this one.....

```
            CGSize maximumSize1 = CGSizeMake(100, 9999);
            NSString *myString1 = @"When in the Course of human events, it becomes necessary for one people to dissolve the political bands which have connected them with another, and to assume among the powers of the earth, the separate and equal station to which the Laws of Nature and of Nature's God entitle them, a decent respect to the opinions of mankind requires that they should declare the causes which impel them to the separation.When in the Course of human events, it becomes necessary for one people to dissolve the political bands which have connected them with another, and to assume among the powers of the earth, the separate and equal station to which the Laws of Nature and of Nature's God entitle them, a decent respect to the opinions of mankind requires that they should declare the causes which impel them to the separation.";
            UIFont *myFont1 = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];//[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];


            UILabel *lbl_Title=[[UILabel alloc] init];
            lbl_Title.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeClip;
            CGSize myStringSize1 = [myString1 sizeWithFont:myFont1 
                                         constrainedToSize:maximumSize1 
                                             lineBreakMode:lbl_Title.lineBreakMode];
            lbl_Title.frame=CGRectMake(20, 10, myStringSize1.width, myStringSize1.height);
            lbl_Title.font=myFont1;
            //      lbl_Title.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
            lbl_Title.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            lbl_Title.numberOfLines=100;
            lbl_Title.text=myString1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the bounds property.

```
sv.bounds.size.height
```

Answer (score 3):

either of the following should do the trick...

```
<ullabel>.frame.size.height
<uilabel>.bounds.size.height
```

Use NSLog to take a look...

```
NSLog(@"%f", myLabel.bounds.size.height);
NSLog(@"%f", myLabel.frame.size.height);
```