# UILabel multiple line in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

I have created a custom view cell with a UILabel in it, I have set :

```
 cell.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
       cell.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

and it's not going in multiple lines, why is this?

in the layoutSubviews I have:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect frame = titleLabel.frame;
    frame.origin.y = 5;
    titleLabel.frame = frame;
}
```

and that's about all the settings I have, however for a long text put in the label in the cell it just  won't word wrap:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the height of the label's frame? It needs to be tall enough to hold more than one line of text. Check out [Adjust UILabel height depending on the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446405/adjust-uilabel-height-depending-on-the-text)

Comment: should this be set at the layoutSubview in the Cell class or inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: in a UITextView, I used to do frame.size.height = title.contentSize.height;
, but what is the equivalent of this in UILabel?