# Draw UILabel depends upon string in DrawRect method

Tags: iphone

In my application I want to draw UILabel dynamically depends upon string  in DrawRect method...How can draw this?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific, please? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the UILabel frame according to your textSize?? If so, refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446405/adjust-uilabel-height-depending-on-the-text).

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below..

It worked for me in the case of button title. :)

```
CGRect oldLblRect = lbl1.frame;
        lbl1.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
        [lbl1 sizeToFit];
        lbl1.frame = CGRectMake(lbl1.frame.origin.x - ((lbl1.frame.size.width - oldLblRect.size.width)/2), lbl1.frame.origin.y - ((lbl1.frame.size.height - oldLblRect.size.height)/2), lbl1.frame.size.width, lbl1.frame.size.height);
```

Hope it helps. :)