# dynamically size the height of the tableView cells

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I am able to display the cell content in the table and also Wordwrap it to display the message entirely. But I noticed that if the content is more than the height than it becomes clumpsy. How do I increase the heighten a cell dynamically if the content is too large. Since I am retrieving data from a url the length varies so I do not want to hard code the height but want to vary it as per the content length.

The code that I have tried so far is as under :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *person = [myPeople objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; 

    NSString *personName = [person valueForKey:@"text"];

    NSString *cellText    = personName;
    UIFont *cellFont      = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-neuve" size:21.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize      = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    int buffer  = 70;
    return labelSize.height + buffer;
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";  

    UITableViewCell *cell = [commentView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];  
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 6;
        cell.textLabel.font          = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-neuve" size:21.0];
        [cell.textLabel setMinimumFontSize:13.0];
        [cell.textLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:NO];
    } 
    NSDictionary *person = [myPeople objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; 

    NSString *personName = [person valueForKey:@"text"];
    cell.textLabel.text = personName;
    return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much as I dislike posting just a link. This will show you how to calculate the correct height for your cell on the fly.

[Adjust UILabel height depending on the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446405/adjust-uilabel-height-depending-on-the-text)

Comment: But I want to adjust cell height

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I see you are already using that method. What happens when you hook willDrawCell with the same approach.