# Dynamically change UITable cell height?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-simulator

I need to resize the cell height based on the content size/length.tried several methods, which one gives the exact height without overlapping?

Comment: check my answer given here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12600584/1538079

Comment: Do you got the answer which is useful to implement?

Comment: yup..Customizing UITableViewCell's height.. this helped me

Comment: -(CGFloat)getLabelHeightForText:(NSString *)text andWidth:(CGFloat)labelWidth
{
    
    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(labelWidth, 10000);
    
    //provide appropriate font and font size
    CGSize labelHeighSize = [text sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:13.0f]
                             constrainedToSize:maximumSize
                                 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
    return labelHeighSize.height;
}

Comment: @RamkumarThiyyakat check the post by Foram Mukund Shah

Comment: Your questions meant that you wants to set tableview cell height dynamically.

Comment: @Deepak i think you want to change the UITableViewCell Dynamically, m i right??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5103517/1059705 http://stackoverflow.com/q/8030608/1059705

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see this tutorial for change `UITableViewCell` Height Dynamically..

[Resizing-A-UITableViewCell](http://www.raddonline.com/blogs/geek-journal/iphone-sdk-resizing-a-uitableviewcell-to-hold-variable-amounts-of-text/)

and also use this tutorial..

[uitableviewcell-dynamic-height](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/)

also use **tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:** method for set height of cell with `indexpath`

Answer (score 3):

This is from my previous answer - [Customizing UITableViewCell's height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123540/customizing-uitableviewcells-height/13124268#13124268):

Use this method to get the text height of the text

```
-(CGFloat)getLabelHeightForText:(NSString *)text andWidth:(CGFloat)labelWidth
{

CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(labelWidth, 10000);

//provide appropriate font and font size
CGSize labelHeighSize = [text sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:13.0f]
                         constrainedToSize:maximumSize
                             lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
return labelHeighSize.height;
}
```

This method will return the height of the text you are passing. Add this method in your class.  And use the  **tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:** delegate method to set the height for each cell

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   Feedback *item = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   CGFloat textHeight = [self getLabelHeightForText:item.comment andWidth:162];//give your label width here
    return textHeight;
}
```

Comment: Feedback *item = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: what does this mean? can you please explain?i mean by Feedback .

Comment: That was the answer for his question. Feedback is an object and it stores the value from an array.

Comment: hey,What is feedback? Is it a class of urs?  may i know what all you do in that particular class

Answer (score 2):

Sample you can edit and try

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath         *)indexPath {

NSDictionary *itemAtIndex = (NSDictionary *)[chatQuestions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if ([self sizeForText:[itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"text"]].height+20>50) {
    return [self sizeForText:[itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"text"]].height+20;
}
else{
    return 50;}



}

 -(CGSize)sizeForText:(NSString*)text
  {


CGSize constraintSize;

constraintSize.width = 190.0f;

constraintSize.height = MAXFLOAT;
UIFont *labelFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Noteworthy-Light" size:18];

CGSize stringSize =[text sizeWithFont:labelFont constrainedToSize: constraintSize lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

return stringSize;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Calculate the expected size based on the font and linebreak mode of your label
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(296,9999);

CGSize expectedLabelSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:yourLabel.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:yourLabel.lineBreakMode];   

//adjust the label the the new height.
CGRect newFrame = yourLabel.frame;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
yourLabel.frame = newFrame;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to set the height of cell based on the label.

Check the link :

http://dcraziee.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/calculate-size-of-uillabel-base-on-text-in/

There is a function named

```
-(CGFloat)getHeightForLabel:(NSString *)_str font:(UIFont *)fontOfObject
```

Use that function to calculate height as :

```
-(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat _height  = [self getHeightForLabel:self.label.text font:[self.label font]];
    return _height;
}
```