# How to set dynamic label size in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I have TableViewCell and load data by web service (JSON), Data stored in different-different array and data load in tableview. I want to array data size some time large and some time small. so how will manage label size. I tried may examples but do not make dynamic label. please help, Thank You.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return  1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [title count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //NSLog(@"tableview cell");
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"event"];
    if (cell==nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [img objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
    cell.img.image =image;

    cell.lbl_1.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    cell.lbl_2.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[des objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.lbl_3.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[evnt_ary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return  cell;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate : - http://stackoverflow.com/q/13190425/3515115

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/ see this link

Comment: @balkaransingh please wait I see this link

Comment: @balkaransingh I follow your link but I used tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension; and cell height is very small. and remove this line cell hight is static size. i want to both size are dynamic label and cell

Comment: @A.Kumawat wait i will give you a demo.

Comment: @balkaransingh thanks a lot solve my problem:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and use it like:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

Make sure your constraints are proper.

Comment: have you used heightforRowAtIndexpath if Yes Then return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

Comment: Please Make sure your Label has numberOfLines=0 and Label LineBrakingMode to nslinebreakbywordwrapping

Comment: But how to label size dynamic?

Comment: yes sure my label numberoflines=0 and word wrapping set in directly storyboard inspector

Comment: @A.Kumawat you need to set proper autolayout of your label.

Comment: @balkaransingh proper set auto-layout of my label but do not set dynamic label. how it possible please help, i'm very tired

Comment: @SagarShirbhate I used tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension and my cell size is very small. then i commented this line label is dynamic but cell size is not increases or decrease.

Comment: @A.Kumawat I Think There is some minor bug is there in code Please go through the http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/ by which you got a better Idea.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to write **[yourCell.yourlabel sizeToFit]** after assigning text to that label.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    yourCell.yourlabel.text = @"text whatever you want to set";
    [yourCell.yourlabel sizeToFit];
}
```

Also assign text to **yourCell.yourlabel** and write [yourCell.yourlabel sizeToFit] in heightForRowAtIndexPath.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    yourCustomCell *yourCellObj = (yourCustomCell *)[self tableView:self.tableViewObj cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    yourCellObj.yourlabel.text = @"text whatever you want to set";
    [yourCellObj.yourlabel sizeToFit];

    return (yourCellObj.yourlabel.frame.origin.y + yourCellObj.yourlabel.frame.size.height);
}
```

Comment: In this code don't use both lines _table_view.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0;
  //  _table_view.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;?

Comment: I am not sure, but when i tried estimatedRowHeight sometimes i got wrong output.

Comment: Make sure you set **yourCellObj.numberOfLines = 0** @A.Kumawat

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use custom cell for your tableView. If you use label directly on tableView, it will cause loading problems when you change it's size dynamically.

Then in "cellForRowAtIndexPath", you can change it properties. For example, if "TableCell" is your custom cell then

```
 TableCell *cell = (NBEServicesCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:"@yourIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Assigning each row a number.
[cell.yourLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Heavy" size:14.0]];
cell.yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.yourLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
[cell.yourLabel sizeToFit];
cell.yourlabel.frame.size.width = newWidth;
cell.yourlabel.frame.size.height = newHeight;
```

Comment: how to write newWidth and newHeight?

Comment: CGFloat newWidth = 100.0

Comment: If you solve your problem, the please vote my answer :)

Comment: Same issue please help me @wasimSafdar

Comment: There is another thing, you can do. You can fix size and write data in multiple lines. Check my edited answer.

Comment: May be, then you do not need to adjust dynamic width, height if you use multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(width_specified, CGFLOAT_MAX);


CGSize myStringSize = [myString sizeWithFont:myFont 
                           constrainedToSize:maximumSize 
                               lineBreakMode:self.myLabel.lineBreakMode];
```

You can calculate the height required by string to fit in lable or textview  for the given width.

You also need to specify the font for the string. ie. font used in container of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get dynamic width & height depending on content (text) of label so you can use following function it will return CGSize you just pass your label parameter.

```
- (CGSize ) messageSizeExact:(UILabel *) msgLabel
{

    CGRect textRect = [msgLabel.text boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){280.0, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                            options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                         attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:msgLabel.font}
                                            context:nil];

    return textRect.size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

plz take the outlet of table

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *view_tableView;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view_tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50;
    self.view_tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


#pragma mark - TableView Delegate And DataSource



-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{


    return 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"mycell"];
    UILabel *label =(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5000];

    label.text=@"Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.2016-07-15 15:22:28.819 Time'nTask[257:14278] Notification settings registered2016-07-15 15:22:28.820 Time'nTask[257:14278] Successfully registered for remote notifications With device Token 68048cc293d695fd3220cf63da3baa685675126ecd72af0547b760ee31571b62";

    return cell;
}
```

rember set label number of line = 0

[image]