# UILabel shows only first line of the text despite I set label.numberOfLines = 0

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I created custom UITableViewCell.

```
@interface AnswerCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *detailTextLabel;
@end
```

and set detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

```
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kAnswerIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AnswerCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell=answerCell;
        }            

        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self extractText:indexPath forLabelAttribute:kDetailTextLabel];
        cell.detailTextLabel.font = [self extractFont:indexPath forLabelAttribute:kDetailTextLabel];
        cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

UILabel shows only first line of the text. But why?

UPDATE: My detailTextLabel's height = 21. What do I need to do? Do I need to change height = 1000?

Comment: Is the `UILabel` big enough to display more than 1 line? It won't resize for you.

Comment: You are right, please see my updated question.

Comment: Looks like people beat me to the actual answer then :-). You should be all set with those answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you cannot show all text because label height is too small. You need to set required height depending on the text length.

See answer for [Adjust UILabel height depending on the text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/447065/194544)

Comment: Thanks - I am resizing cells in a UICollectionView, expanding to show full text when tapped, and resetting the frame of the UILabel to the contentView.bounds was all it needed.

Comment: If you do everything right and still have the problem. Exactly, check the height of the label.

Answer (score 1):

You need to resize your UILabel .. calculate its height using -

```
[contentsStr sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0f]
```

and then resize it accordingly

you may need to change font and its size

Answer (score 1):

If you have the width of the label, get the size of the string that would be required to show the string using the following method,

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size
```

And set the size to the label.

The [Apple documentation](http://www.google.co.in/url?url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont%3a&rct=j&q=sizewithfont+nsstring&usg=AFQjCNGkC3IoQblbWOH_UlY_GOATbkuhjg&sa=X&ei=bg0QT_yNGInyrQf-yun5AQ&ved=0CFwQygQwBA) can be seen here.

Comment: [label sizeToFit]; - is more elegant than sizeWithFont