# uiview fixing the contents

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

my `UIView` has a `UILabel` and a `UIWebView` inside, the `UILabel` is in the top, the UILabel has the height variable:

```
theTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", noticeTitle];
theTitle.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
theTitle.numberOfLines = 0;
[theTitle sizeToFit];
```

how can I start the `UIWebView` below the UILabel?

Thank you in advance.

Regards.

Comment: you can load request immediately after loading label, what is the issue?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand you, I'm newbie. How can I do that?

Comment: UIWebView takes a few quantum to load the contents so if you load webview after this, it'll take a while to show up the contents...that it..!!

Comment: please add some more information.

Comment: -1 What do you mean with "start"? Start after what finished?

Comment: I think it's about layout. I think he/she wants to place the web view right below the label.

Comment: yes, dasdom described exactly what I want

Comment: Add UIWebview first after that add UILabel in self.view.Dont try it in xib.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want your webView to be displayed just below the label.If the string you want to display is dynamic then your Label size must also be dynamically set according to the string size. So for adjusting your label size Just follow the link :

[Adjust UILabel height depending on the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446405/adjust-uilabel-height-depending-on-the-text)

And then you can get the height of your label by :

```
 int height = theTitle.frame.size.height;
```

You then set your webView frame according to this height + yValue of label frame.