# sizewithfont always returns the same value no matter what string is used

Tags: ios, uitableview, sizewithfont

I want to calculate the height of a tableviewcell according to its text. I'm using

```
CGSize userInputSize = [userLabel sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:18.0f] forWidth:[tableView frame].size.width-10 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping]
```

but somehow the return value is always 22 (size of the font). Strange thing is that when I'm using

```
CGSize userInputSize = [userLabel sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:18.0f] constrainedToSize:[tableView frame].size lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

all works fine. But I would prefer the first version, so I can easily adjust the width. Why isn't it working?

Edit: sorry for the bad name convention, but userLabel is a NSString not a label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeWithFont` is a `NSString` method (UIKit additions). use:

```
CGSize userInputSize = [userLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:18.0f] constrainedToSize:[tableView frame].size lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

or

```
CGSize userInputSize = [userLabel.text sizeWithFont:userLabel.font constrainedToSize:[tableView frame].size lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

See [NSString UIKit Additions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html).

**EDIT:**

I just tried this code:

```
NSLog (@"test: %@", NSStringFromCGSize([@"test" sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:18.0f]]));
NSLog (@"longer test: %@", NSStringFromCGSize([@"longer test" sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:18.0f]]));
```

and result is:

```
test: {30, 22}
longer test: {85, 22}
```

`CGSize` is a `struct`:

```
struct CGSize {
   CGFloat width;
   CGFloat height;
};
typedef struct CGSize CGSize;
```

So you're probably looking at `size.height` instead of `size.width`

**EDIT2:**

from documentation [sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006893-CH3-SW7)

> If the size of the string exceeds the given width, this method
>   truncates the text (for layout purposes only) using the specified line
>   break mode until it does conform to the maximum width; it then returns
>   the size of the resulting truncated string.

So you'll be better of defining a maximum size (real `width` and a big `height`) and go with the:

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
```

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/447065/653513).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but userLabel is actually of NSString type. So anybody got an idea why the first one won't work while the second one does?

Comment: Can you check (with `NSLog`) a size of `[tableView frame].size`?

Comment: Or try (just to check) what  `[userLabel sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:18.0f]` returns.

Comment: `[tableView frame].size` is 320 and `[userLabel sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:18.0f]` is 22

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my problem is the height as I said in my question. I try to calculate the correct height for the cell and i thought the first method `CGSize userInputSize = [userLabel sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:18.0f] forWidth:[tableView frame].size.width-10 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping]` would return the correct height, but it's always 22 while the second method returns the correct height. I hope my question is clear now :-D

Comment: Sorry for that - it's clear now :). Yes, that method simply truncates the string if it's to wide (for one line). That's why you should use the second option.

Comment: i should start using the docu more... :/ Thanks a lot for pointing this out! :D

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier this way. After setting the "text" property of the userLabel, call this method.

```
[userLabel sizeToFit];
```

At this point, the userLabel.frame has been changed so that it fits the text with the selected font. You can use userLabel.frame.size.height to adjust your table view cell.