# How do I get StringSize to return a useful height?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

MonoTouch makes the `sizeWithFont` methods available through `UIView`, but it seems to return the font's `LineHeight` no matter how long the string I pass to it.

```
string someString = "test string";
UIFont someFont = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(13f);
SizeF sizeToDisplay = someUIView.StringSize(someString, someFont, Bounds.Width, UILineBreakMode.WordWrap);
// sizeToDisplay = { Width: 58, Height = 16 }
someString = string.Join(" ", Enumerable.Repeat(someString, 500));
sizeToDisplay = someUIView.StringSize(someString, someFont, Bounds.Width, UILineBreakMode.WordWrap);
// sizeToDisplay = { Width: 304, Height = 16 }
```

Is there some other method I should be using to find the height needed to display an arbitrary block of text in a `UITextView`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This [isn't specific to MonoTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13304904/48700), but you'd have to search for the native `NSString.sizeWithFont` method to find that answer, so this should help other MonoTouch devs in the future.

For some reason, you will need to hit a [different overload for `StringSize`](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aMonoTouch.Foundation.NSString.StringSize(MonoTouch.UIKit.UIFont%2cSystem.Drawing.SizeF)), one that takes a full `SizeF` argument instead of a width value. In this case, you just "hack" in a very large height to get the wrapped-text size.

```
SizeF sizeToDisplay = someUIView.StringSize(someString, someFont, new SizeF(Bounds.Width, float.MaxValue), UILineBreakMode.WordWrap);
// For the larger string: sizeToDisplay = { Width: 307, Height = 1600 }
```

That `forWidth` overload of `StringSize` calls over to [the native `sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:` `NSString` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006893-CH3-SW7). For some reason, when you use this overload, it will truncate your string for measurement purposes.

> This method returns the width and height of the string constrained to the specified width. Although it computes where line breaks would occur, this method does not actually wrap the text to additional lines. If the size of the string exceeds the given width, this method truncates the text (for layout purposes only) using the specified line break mode until it does conform to the maximum width; it then returns the size of the resulting truncated string.

#### Note about UITextView padding

As a side note, using a `UITextView` with the returned `StringSize` will result in text that requires scrolling to see (`UITextView` inherits from `UIScrollView`) because it includes some forced content padding. You will need to also [tweak the content offsets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/746670/48700) to get what you expect.

```
someUITextView.ContentInset = new UIEdgeInsets(-8, -8, -8, -8);
```